# SwipeDismissAdapter with click event

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, swipe-gesture

I'm using [the library ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/) for implementing swipe to dismiss using a SwipeDismissAdapter. I can make it work if I do not add a OnClickListener to the view in the adapter, but I want also to carry out some action when the item is clicked (and not swiped). I looks like the OnClickListener is intercepting the swipe gesture, but I do not know how to avoid it.

My relevant code: in the activity, when creating the adapter:

```
SwipeDismissAdapter dismissAdapter = new SwipeDismissAdapter(myAdapter,
            myOnDismissCallback);

dismissAdapter.setAbsListView(listView);
listView.setAdapter(dismissAdapter);
```

On the getView for my adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.something, parent, false);
    }

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```